# Sorting complex dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

i'm trying to sort in order a complex dataframe in Python. Any help is greatly appreciated!

my data looks like this:

```
23-AU
23-AU
23-BS
24_BS
11
23
AB 
N/A
N/A
24_BC
24BC
```

How can I sort those strings in python?
Thanks,

Comment: Show us the ocmplete dataframe, not sure what columns you have, how many rows and etc. Not clear if what you gave are in one column or not.

Comment: We need a lot more information in order to help. For example, in what order do you want these sorted? Are these values all strings or are they mixed type (`int`, `str`, `na.nan`)? etc.

Comment: you should at least explain which exact output you expect and the underlying logic

Answer (score 0):

no dataframe here at all. its just strings...
so just put it into a list and call sorted on that list.

my_strs = [ "23-AU", "23-AU", "23-BS" ]

sorted(my_strs)

Python Dataframe is a big framework with options to call it from inside the framework on the actual data.
Your strings doesnt describe anything, except that they are str or objs.

Use the pandas options here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html

start there and use the build-in Functions :)

If your data in the dataframe is compareable, use https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html

or the greater, lowerthan functions.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cost': [250, 150, 100],

               'revenue': [100, 250, 300]},

              index=['A', 'B', 'C'])
print(df)
print(df == 100)
```

Than you can play with the > or >= my_value
even compare your dataframes.